Jetpack Coil GIF loaded from localPath
I'm getting started on android development, specifically for WearOS so I don't know much about it.
I'd like to display a gif but not loaded from R.drawable.
From my understanding, drawables are getting "elaborated" during the compile process. Since I will need a LOT of gifs, uploading and setting their density one by one on the ResourceManager uploader will be impossibile. Moreover, when the amount of assets will get high, I won't be able to compile it anymore.
Looking up online, I was able to create a module called "shared" just to host my gifs and I uploaded there my files.
shared > scr > main > assets > folder > sample.gif
project file tree
So far so good, I'm able to access my static images using the filePath.
Now I want to display the gifs but I'm not able to do it.
The code so far:
@ExperimentalCoilApi  
@Composable  
fun GifImage(filePath: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {  
    val inputStream: InputStream = LocalContext.current.assets.open("dex/$filePath"). 
    val bufferedSource = inputStream.source().buffer()  
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(LocalContext.current).build(). 

    var loadingState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        imageLoader = imageLoader,
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(bufferedSource)
            .decoderFactory(
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory()
                else GifDecoder.Factory())
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .build(),
        onSuccess = {
            loadingState = true
        }
    )

    if (loadingState){
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    } else {
        Text("Loading")
    }

}

I also tried to use AsyncImage but no way.
If I have my gif uploaded as a drawable and use

.data(R.drawable.filename)

it works but not with the filePath that used to work with a static image (.png)
Screenshot

Your screenshot shows a directory named dex.133. Your code uses a directory of dex. These need to match.

I think this answer will help you. Also, you can go with Lottie Animation. You said that you tried AsyncImage but have you Enable GIF loader before using AsyncImage.  If not, see the article.

@CommonsWare Thanks for pointing it out but I'm sure they are correct. The string passed to the Composable method contains the subdir (133). In that folder I have both .png and .gif file. Using .png at the end of the string displays the image correctly, .gif doesn't

@PremDanej I looked at the article you posted and that's exactly where I started. Looking at it again, I noticed that I had never used videoEnabledLoader so I did a test with the help of chatgpt https://imgur.com/a/nltwFBm and this is the result: https://i.imgur.com/FropIQj.png but the error persist... inputStream doesn't work, R.drawable works

@PremDanej urls are broken so I've re-uploaded them
https://i.ibb.co/5LmXLth/Screenshot-2024-09-06-at-08-04-44.png
https://i.ibb.co/ysYvtBv/FropIQj.png

@MirkoSpinato On the other hand you can do 1 thing. Convert your gif to JSON and display it using LottieAnimation. I think this helps you.
